# No AuthenticationProvider found for PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I'm fairly new at the whole Spring Security thing, and I'm trying to set up a website that uses pre-authentication. I have followed some examples and tutorials and I think it's going well. But i have stucked on one thing.

When i navigate through the .jsp pages everything works fine. I can access the "public" pages, and i get "Access Denied" when i try to access the "private" pages (I haven't finished the filter for private pages).

But if I check the logs when navigating I get the same error everytime accessing a page:

> org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderNotFoundException: No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken

The thing is, I have a Provider for this, or at least I think so.

SecurityConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean(name = "myAuthenticationManager")
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception
    {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }


    @Bean
    public AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager()
    {
        List<AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object>> decisionVoters
                = Arrays.asList(new RoleVoter());

        return new AffirmativeBased(decisionVoters);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider provider = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider();

        DlaUserDetailsService userDetailsService = new DlaUserDetailsService();
        provider.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        auth.authenticationProvider(provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        DlaSpringMvcFilter filter = new DlaSpringMvcFilter();
        AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = this.authenticationManager();
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);

        http.addFilter(filter).authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/private/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll();

        http.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

What have I done wrong here? Am I missing something?